# Meteor and Semantic UI: Variable undefined

Tags: meteor, less, semantic-ui

I'm working on my first Meteor project and I've run into a bit of a bump with Semantic. I'm using the `semantic:ui` package along with the suggested autoprefixer package. I've gone about generating all the code as the docs show and it appears to be working fine - my page's style has changed. I'm leaving it at its default configuration for now.

However, whenever I try to use a Semantic variable in a Less file (i.e. `@primaryColor`), Meteor crashes and tells me that it's undefined. I get this error no matter what I do. I've tried directly importing the site.variables into my LESS file and it still gives me the error.

It's getting pretty frustrating since it seems like it should be pretty simple. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Anguiac7, without showing us your code, and/or the error you are seeing, this is not a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that worked for me (I'm sure there's more than one) is to build my application-specific less in the same local package as Meteor's `semantic:ui` build location. Then provide a relative path to the semantic variables in your application-specific less directory (or directories):

```
// import variables from semantic via relative path

@import (optional) '../themes/default/globals/site.variables';
@import (optional) '../site/globals/site.variables.import.less';

// begin app specific less

@import 'myApp.import.less';
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have worked. It's weird because I thought that Meteor would automatically stitch everything together for me.